# Making systeme use superscripts

Tags: systeme

I want to make a system of linear equations in LaTeX and I'm using `systeme` for that. The problem is that I want indices to be superscripted like this:

[image]

because that's the notation we use. Yet `systeme` uses bottom indexing and if I try to do that it gives an error:

```
\[
\systeme{x^1 + x^2 + x^3 = 1}
\]
```

> Package systeme Error: l'inconnue "x_{-1}" a deja ete trouvee dans l'equation !.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: can you supply an example document so people can test answers? (add it to the question in a code block, `{}` in the editor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the command `\syssubstitute` (to be found in the `systeme` documentation), like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}
\syssubstitute{{x_1}{x^1}{x_2}{x^2}{x_3}{x^3}}
\systeme{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1}
\end{document}
```